# Android − black background turn into grey

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm explicitly defining a black color to the background of my LinearLayout (using @android:color/black in my XML), but sometimes (often after a screen rotation), the black is turning into a grey color (or a transparent black).

This problem appears on many devices: both on emulator, Acer Liquid (Android 2.2) and Galaxy Nexus (Android 4.1).

Screenshots: [Buggy view](http://pix.keuse.fr/?v=buggy.png) // [Not buggy view](http://pix.keuse.fr/?v=notbuggy.png)

Here is my XML and activity code:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:minHeight="150dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/projectview_description_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/projectview_description_image_description"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/project_nophoto" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/projectview_description_overlay"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:height="35dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/projectview_description_title"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/projectview_description_baseline"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- This LinearLayout background is buggy -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@android:color/black">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/project_status_finish" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/projectview_description_website"
                android:textColor="@color/website_link"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:id="@+id/projectview_description_website" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/projectview_description_about_container"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/projectview_description_about"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/projectview_description_about_text" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/projectview_description_questions_container" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Activity:

```
public class ProjectViewActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private boolean displayMenu = false;
    private Intent shareIntent;
    private FavoriteSqlite db;
    private I4pProjectTranslation project;

    @TargetApi(14)
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if(displayMenu) {
            // Inflate menu only if it hasn't been done before
            if(menu.size() == 0) {
                // Inflating the menu
                MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.projectview, menu);

                // Creating share intent
                Intent prepareShareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                prepareShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, UriHelper.getProjectUrl(project));
                prepareShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, project.getTitle());
                prepareShareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(prepareShareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.projectview_menu_share_dialog));
            }

            // Defining favorite state
            MenuItem favoriteItem = menu.getItem(0);
            if(db.isFavorite(project))
                favoriteItem.setTitle(R.string.projectview_menu_favorites_remove);
            else
                favoriteItem.setTitle(R.string.projectview_menu_favorites_add);
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            if(getIntent().getData() != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomepageActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else 
                finish();
            break;
        case R.id.projectview_favorite:
            Toast t;
            if(db.isFavorite(project)) {
                db.removeFavorite(project);
                t = Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.projectview_toast_favorites_remove, project.getTitle()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            } else {
                db.addFavorite(project);
                t = Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.projectview_toast_favorites_add, project.getTitle()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
            t.show();
            break;
        case R.id.projectview_share:
            startActivity(shareIntent);
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @TargetApi(11)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.loading);
        db = new FavoriteSqlite(this);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        project = (I4pProjectTranslation) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
        if(project != null)
            displayProject();
        else {
            String projectLang;
            String projectSlug;

            Uri data = getIntent().getData();
            if(data != null) {
                List<String> path = data.getPathSegments();
                projectLang = path.get(0);
                projectSlug = path.get(2);
            } else {
                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

                if(extras.containsKey("project_title"))
                    setTitle(extras.getString("project_title"));

                projectLang = extras.getString("project_lang");
                projectSlug = extras.getString("project_slug");
            }

            ProjectViewHandler handler = new ProjectViewHandler(this);
            ProjectViewThread thread = new ProjectViewThread(handler, projectLang, projectSlug);

            thread.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
        return project;
    }

    public void setProject(I4pProjectTranslation p) {
        project = p;
    }

    @TargetApi(11)
    public void displayProject() {
        setContentView(R.layout.projectview_description);
        displayMenu = true;
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // Rebuild the menu

        setTitle(project.getTitle());

        LinearLayout overlay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.projectview_description_overlay);
        overlay.getBackground().setAlpha(127);

        if(project.getProject().getPictures().size() > 0) {
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.projectview_description_image);
            image.setImageBitmap(project.getProject().getPictures().get(0).getImageBitmap());
        }

        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.projectview_description_title);
        title.setText(project.getTitle());

        TextView baseline = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.projectview_description_baseline);
        baseline.setText(project.getBaseline());

        TextView website = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.projectview_description_website);
        if("".equals(project.getProject().getWebsite()))
            website.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        else
            website.setOnClickListener(this);

        if("".equals(project.getAboutSection())) {
            LinearLayout aboutContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.projectview_description_about_container);
            aboutContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            TextView aboutText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.projectview_description_about_text);
            aboutText.setText(project.getAboutSection());
        }

        LinearLayout questions = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.projectview_description_questions_container);
        for(Question question : project.getProject().getQuestions()) {
            if(question.getAnswer() != null) {
                LinearLayout questionLayout = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.projectview_question, null);

                TextView questionView = (TextView) questionLayout.findViewById(R.id.projectview_question_question);
                TextView answerView = (TextView) questionLayout.findViewById(R.id.projectview_question_answer);

                questionView.setText(question.getQuestion());
                answerView.setText(question.getAnswer().trim());

                questions.addView(questionLayout);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(project.getProject().getWebsite()));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is due to a bug in the framework's caching mechanism. The easiest workaround is to use a color that's almost black, such as `#ff010101`.

Comment: What is the proper fix for this ? or shall i say is there a proper fix for this? And is there something on the google bug tracker?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining the black colour attribute on every instance of the Layout, have you tried setting a custom style with that attribute? On the one hand, it's better for maintenance, but on the other hand, maybe the styling engine deals better with configuration changes and the problem will be solved.

Comment: I've tried to [make a style](http://paste.keuse.fr/view/75698231.html), but it don't works, black background still mystically going to grey (as you can see on screenshots added to 1st post). Thanks for help :)